# hibernate set property to trigger a database update

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

#### I just found a strange problem in Hibernate.

In My Java EE web project within Hibernate framework and json-plugin. My code like this

```
private User user;
get(),set()....

public String getUser(){
   if(findUser(...) != null){
       user = findUser(...);
       user.setPasssword("")//!important for the purpose of  does not transmit the password to the front
       return "success";
   } else {
       return "error";
   }
}
```

the problem appeared when the code executed the User's password in database be cleared, I'm sure any update and insert function dosen't be triggered.

I want to know why? who can figure it out and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the base principle of an ORM like Hibernate: you manipulate objects mapped to database tables, and attached to a persistent session, and every changes you make on these objects are automatically recorded, transparently, in the database.

If you want your changes to the User object not recorded in the database, you need to first detach the object from the Hibernate session, using `session.evict(user)`.

You don't seem to have grasped basic (and very important) principles of Hibernate. Read its [excellent documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/).

Comment: Thank you very much,as you said I dosen't have grasped basic principles of hibernate. now the problem has been resolved，thanks again.